# x and y can be no greater than 2D

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to plot the prediction, here are my codes:

```
    y_pred_FF = model_LSTM.predict(X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],1))

plt.plot(y_test, "b-+", label='Ground truth', color = "red")
plt.plot(y_pred_FF, "b-", label='Feed Forward prediction', color = "blue")
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(0,18)
plt.xlim(0, 200)
plt.xlabel('Time instances', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Activity', fontsize=16)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

and this is the error when I run these codes:

```
ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2D, but have shapes (14152,) and (14152, 1, 1)
```

in the plot it only draws the y_test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that y has 3 axes/is 3D because its size is `(14152, 1, 1)`. The last two dimensions just have a size of 1, and you can get rid of these redundant axes using

```py
import numpy as np
y_pred_FF_squeezed = np.squeeze(y_pred_FF)
print('Shape before:', y_pred_FF.shape, ', shape after:', y_pred_FF_squeezed.shape)
```

For plotting use `y_pred_FF_squeezed`.